# Auto-increment a form from a list of words

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have no skills in this kind of technologies, but I know it can do some awesome stuff. So I hope you will be able to help me.

Here is my project: I want to create a form on which I can submit a list (with a predetermined separator) and it will take all the elements of the list, and increment a number for each occurrence.

The objective is to have a statistic result.

Example: I have two lists, one with 3 times the word `apple` and 2 times the word `car`, and another with the same words, 5 times and 1 time. I would be able to paste one list in a text answer and get as a result `3` and `2`, in the categories apple and car, and when I paste the second list, it would add the result and become `8` and `3`.

I'm sorry, I know it's confusing, because of my lack of knowledge of those technologies and also my English, which is far from perfect.

I hope someone understands my request and can help me with that, it would be awesome!

Comment: you probably mean **google spreadsheet** not **google form**, right?

Comment: Yes sorry! That was a msitake (I've been trying to find a way to do what I want on both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to do something like:

**`=COUNTIF(SPLIT(B5; ","; 1; 1);  "apple")`**

where you count occurrences of **`"apple"`** in cell **B5** where there is predetermined a comma separator **`","`**

[image]

and here you can try it out: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gy3cG7ObNjZhkiRjlGA3NDIphrntbMZGx_ivUa4ViMw/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: That's really close of what I imagined! Thanks a lot, I think I'll be able to get the result I expect from this, thanks again!